# Different response using Python requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to download an image from a URL using `requests`. Using browser or a REST client, like [restlet chrome extension](https://restlet.com/modules/client/) I can retrieve the normal content, a json, and a binary image that I can save to disk.

Using `requests` as response result I got almost same response headers, only `Content-Length` has a different value - 15 bytes instead of 35 kilobytes - and I can't found the binary image.

Trying to simulate the request made by the browser I configure the same request header, like this:

```
headers = {"Host": "cpom.prefeitura.sp.gov.br",
           "Pragma": "no-cache",
           "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
           "DNT": "1",
           "Accept": "*/*",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
           "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "
                         "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                         "Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
           }

r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers)
```

There's no redirects, I also debug and look the content of `requests.model.Response` but no success.

What I'm missing? I think that is a detail about the request, but I can't get it.

This my test:

```
url = "https://cpom.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/prestador/SituacaoCadastral/ImagemCaptcha?u=8762520"
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.raw.headers)
    with open("/home/bruno/captcha/8762520.txt", "wb") as f:  # saving as text, since is not the png image
        for chunk in r:
            f.write(chunk)
```

This is the URL to download the image: https://cpom.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/prestador/SituacaoCadastral/ImagemCaptcha?u=4067913

And this the site with the captcha image: https://cpom.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/prestador/SituacaoCadastral

With a simple `GET` will get only a json response body, but inspecting the response you'll see the binary response, which is the image - ~36kb size.

**EDIT**: include images from restlet client

Request:
[image: Request sample]

Response:
[image: Partial response]

Comment: I can only get the 15 byte response with the small JSON, either with Chrome or Postman. Where/how are you getting the response with the image?

Comment: @jdehesa I included a sample request using restlet. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the `Cookie` header. Restlet makes use of existing Chrome's cookies by default ([see docs](https://restlet.com/documentation/client/user-guide/debug-discover/sending#toc_10)), but if you set the `Cookie` header to an empty string you will see you do not get the image. I you want to be able to retrieve the image from a Python script, you will need to obtain first a valid cookie making a request to another valid URL in the web app (for example the link with the form that you posted) and look into the `Set-Cookie` (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) for more information).

Comment: Hum, I see, restlet sets a `Cookie`. I will test this approach.

Comment: Is that, I'm making an another request, getting the `Set-Cookie` header and now I can get the image. Thanks